# REST method return type - Best practicee

Tags: rest

Is it a good idea to always use Response as a return type for all your REST services.
For example, let's say I have a method that gets all customers

```
First way:
public List <customer> getAllCustomers(){
// select all customers from database
}

Second Way:
public Response getAllCustomers(){
// user Response.ResponseBuilder.entity(customer)
}

enter code here
```

Which is a better approach. Is is advisable for all methods to return Response as return type (as in the Second way).

Comment: Please read [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/211275/should-an-http-api-always-return-a-body).  It seems that the spec is a bit thin in this area.

Comment: Response allows you to set status codes, headers, etc. You can't do that returning model objects, without tapping into the `HttpServletResponse` (which is ugly) or using a filter (which is complicated when considering all possible resources). In simple GET cases, where the response is always 200 or 404 (we can throw an exception), it makes sense and is ok to return model objects, but with other methods Response is easier. Personally, I prefer to stay consistent and always return Response.

Answer (score 1):

I would create your own response object. This will let you pass information to the client about the operation, number of records updated, error messages, etc. Also your service will behave consistently to your clients.

I would say you do not have to return any response data, but you should set your HTTP response codes appropriately. Like setting a 204 (No Content) response code for a simple acknowledgement of an operation.